# Magento 2.4.0 The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.4, magento2-migration-tool

I got this error while trying to make category "is_anchor" yes or no. If i save category without changing this "is_anchor" attribute then it works fine.

I have migrated the store from Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.4. I have done migration successfully.

I have tried below steps, still facing same error,

1. truncate the url_rewrite and then reindex URLs for category and products.
2. I have installed this https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites extension and regenates URLs. Still it giving me same error.

Please check below screenshots,

[image]

Please let me know if you guys have proper solution.

Thanks,

Comment: do you have multiple store views? I have seen this problem where one of the store view URL Keys for the product was not correctly set.

Comment: No, i don't have multiple store views.

Comment: Do the affected products save without errors? Try modifying the URL Key for one of them to see if it is then removed from the anchor category errors.